# Cassandra how many columns/row for optimal performance?

Tags: cassandra, range-query

I am writing a chat server and, want to store my messages in cassandra. Because I need range queries and I know that I will expect 100 messages/day and maintain history for 6 months I will have 18000 messages for a user at a point.

Now, since I'll do range queries I need my data to be on the same machine. Either I have to use ByteOrderPartitioner, which I don't understand fully, or I can store all the message for a user on the same row.

```
create table users_conversations(jid1 bigint, jid2 bigint, archiveid timeuuid, stanza text, primary key((jid1, jid2), archiveid)) with CLUSTERING ORDER BY (archiveid DESC );
```

So I'll have 18000 columns. Do you think I'll have performance problems using this cluster key approach?

If yes, what alternative do I have?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Do not use the ByteOrderedPartitioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939234/cassandra-byteorderedpartitioner/27944273#27944273).  I cannot stress enough how important that point is.

> since I'll do range queries I need my data to be on the same machine.

With your PRIMARY KEY defined like this:

```
primary key((jid1, jid2), archiveid)
```

Your current partitioning keys (`jid1` and `jid2`) will be combined and hashed so that all messages for specific values of `jid1` and `jid2` are stored together on the same partition.  The drawback is that you will need both `jid1` and `jid2` for each query.  But they will be sorted on `archiveid`, you will be able to query by range on `archiveid`, and it should perform well as long as you don't hit the 2 billion columns per partition limit.

Comment: Also I intend to use pagination so I wont let the user query all history, but by using pagination of 50 or maximum 100 messages/page. I'm a bit concerned about the very wide row anti pattern, what was the biggest wide row you dealt with Bryce? Many thanks

Comment: @user3030447 I have a few tables with about 8k-12k columns per wide row.  I may repartition them in the future, but for now they're doing well.