# Cassandra: Sort by query

Tags: cassandra

I have a little bit special request.

Constelation: I use a Redis DB to store geo data and use georedius to get them back, sorted by distance. With this keys I search the data in cassandra. But the result of cassandra is sorted in the key or something else.

What I want is, to get the inforamtions back in the same order i requested it. 
The partition key is build from id (I get back form redis) and a status.

Could I tell cassandra to sort by id array?

Answer (score 0):

Partition key are designed to be randomly distributed across different nodes. You can use ByteOrderedPartitioner to do ordered queries. But BOP are considered anti-pattern is cassandra and I will highly recommend against it. You can read more about it here [Cassandra ByteOrderedPartitioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939234/cassandra-byteorderedpartitioner).

You can add more parameters to the Primary Key which will determine how to store data on the disk. These are known as clustering keys. You can do Order By queries on clustering keys. This is a good document on clustering keys https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html.

If you can share more schema details, I can suggest what to use as clustering key.

Comment: Thank you. ok. i hoped there will be a function which sort it afterwards. So I have to do this in my code. I have a longitude and a latitude but but there is no information in the cassandra table to get distance between the search and result point.