# Spark cassandra connector failed to support ByteOrderedParitioner?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I am using `spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.0.0.jar` to connect to Cassandra(version 2.1.9). Cassandra's partitioner is `ByteOrderedParitioner'.

However, when I submit spark driver programs, it shows:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.ByteOrderedPartitioner`.

It seems that only "Murmur3Partitioner" and "RandomPartitioner" are supported in the source code.

But Hadoop supports ByteOrderedPartitioner. I wonder how to solve it when I force to use `ByteOrderedPartitioner`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

It's not in Spark because **nobody** should be using the `ByteOrderedPartitioner` anymore. This is because it:

A) Exists only for backward compatibility.

B) Its creation (and subsequent use) is widely recognized as a **bad** idea.

This has been discussed ad-nauseum.  See my answer here to a similar question: [Cassandra ByteOrderedPartitioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939234/cassandra-byteorderedpartitioner/27944273)

I recommend you:

- Rebuild your cluster using the `Murmur3Partitioner`.
- OR build a *new* cluster, and load it with data from the original.
- Find whomever built the original cluster and ***slap*** them.

Comment: Ok, I was kidding about slapping the person who built that cluster.  Maybe.  At least, that should probably be my official statement.

Comment: I discarded `Murmur3Partitioner` because I found that data amount ingested among nodes differed from each other greatly. But `ByteOrderedPartitioner` was a good choice for loading balance, and it did.  I found that there are implementation of InputFormat in Cassandra's source codes, which supports both `Murmur3Partitioner` and `ByteOrderedPartitioner` and it worked for both Hadoop and Spark.

Comment: If the data isn't very good distributed with Murmur partitioner, then it's a sign of the problems with data model...

Comment: @Jenny.D Alex makes a good point, in that your data model itself needs to be designed for good data distribution.  The bottom line, is that the `ByteOrderedPartitioner` is deprecated, will be removed from Cassandra at some point, and getting support and help around using it will be extremely difficult (as you are finding).